# Excel vba - passing worksheet to a public function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a public function:

```
Public Function Test(wrs As Worksheet, arr As Variant) As Variant
```

and I have main sub:

```
Sub Main()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim out, in

ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 

out = Test (ws, in)
```

Calling the Test I get "ByRef argument type mismatch" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Set keyword like this:

```
set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

**Edit:**

Then make sure that you set the return of the function as well. Like this:

```
Public Function Test() As Variant
    Set Test = ActiveSheet
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print Test.name
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I had that in my code. I forgot to write it down. It's not that

Comment: @user155754 - see the edit, you are probably not setting the return of the function.